# JavaScript - My webpage does not load properly when a write a very simple do/while loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a do...while loop, but my webpage seems to not load once I attach the script. Here is the code:

```
var x = 45;
do {
 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("hello");

}, 3000);

} while (x = 40);
```

What could be the problem?

PS. Sorry for this noob question, I'm quite new to JavaScript and programming in general.

Comment: Change the do-while condition from `while(x=40)` to `while(x<=40)` or `while(x>=40)`, also add one incrementing or decrementing condition inside do while loop

Comment: Check your program logic. You set x to 45, enter the do/while loop (which  should print out hello once, then you set x to 40 (should use x == 40).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite simple. As they commented on your question, there's a mistake of spelling, it should be

```
while(x == 40) OR while(x <= 40) OR while(x >= 40)
```

something like above.
The point is, whatever the statement would be in the prepositions, it must return **true or false on your certain purpose**, and you also have to make sure to change the value which affects the statement.
So for example, it should be like this:

```
var x = 10;

do {
 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("hello");
 }, x * 1000);

 x--;
} while (x >= 1);
```

Then, this code will print 'hello' on console for 10 seconds consecutive. However, you also need to know how and why this code works like this.

When a broswer reads your JavaScript file, by default, it starts from the very top, line:0
So in that code, *var x = 10* will be read and then *do-while* starts to be read after. And if there's one more code below your *do-while*, then it'll be read after finish to read *do-while*. Do you understand this process?

**Conclusion A)** So therefore, it means your code will never be finished to be read before the browser read all of your code.

second, you also need to know how setTimeout works. Basically, JavaScript is a single-threaded programming language. So this langauge does not support you to work many things at the same time. If you felt something worked really fast and has been done at the same time, it's just because your browser worked so fast, so you couldn't even recognize the delay. 

When the interpreter meets async functions, such as setTimeout, it pushs the async task into the task queue and **postpone to affect the result to the browser** or somewhere. 
So it means this:

```
-----------------------------Task Queue ↓------------------------------------
|          (task A) (A's done) (task B) (B's done) (async A) (async A's done)
|----------------------------Wait Queue ↓------------------------------------
| task A ---↑  task B(wait)↑---(push)↑
|     async A(setTimeout:500ms) (wait) ----------(push)↑
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Task A and Task B aren't async functions, so they could be pushed into the task queue as soon as they're pushed in the wait queue, unless the task queue wasn't occupied. If the task queue is occupied, then all works(task B) must wait until the task queue would be empty.

However, the async function, setTimeout, has been already pushed in the wait queue before task B, but it went into the task queue after task B. **Why?**
Because it's how async functions works. 

**Conclusion B)** *Seconds* parameter you've set **doesn't mean that setTimeout will be executed** in *Seconds* seconds. It just means **how long your setTimeout should wait** in the wait queue.

So, as practice for you, guess and think why this code works like this.

```
var x = 10;

do {
 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("hello");
 }, x * 1000);

 x--;
} while (x >= 1);

for(i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
 console.log('hi')
}
```

Last, the problem in your code, was the statement in (). Basically, if you do *while(x = 40)*, it means you want x to be set by 40, however because of *while*, *x = 40* will be evaluated and returned as either true or false. Since the value of x will not be falsy, it'll always be true. That's why your *do-while* works forever. And, if you've read my post well, you can already figure out the second problem. Because the interpreter will stay in *do-while* for good, it can't finish to read all of your codes, meaning is, there's no time to execute setTimeout. (Remember 'postpone'?)

Comment: @pepperjack It's a proper answer for this question.  The person asking the question is just getting start.  Moon went out of their way to provide a good answer.  No TD;DR; needed.